# Generalization of the Bolzano's theorem for mappings in Banach spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces.

What are subsets $M \subset X$ for which the following theorem is true?

Theorem. Let $F: M \to Y$ be continuous and satisfy the following property:
there are points $x_{1}\in M$ and $x_{2}\in M$ such that $F(x_{1}) = -F(x_{2})$.
Then there exists $\xi \in M$ such that $F(\xi)=0$.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: If $X=\mathbb{R}^2$, the result would fail with $X=M$, if the dimension of $Y$ is at least $1$.

Answer (score 2):

There is absolutely no hope for such a characterization.

Take for example, the following $2-$dimensional example (imagine how much worse are thing in infinite dimensions):

$$
f(x,y)=(\mathrm{e}^x\cos y,\mathrm{e}^x\sin y), \quad (x,y)\in \mathbb R^2.
$$
Clearly $f$ is $C^\infty$,
$$
f(x,y+\pi)=-f(x,y),
$$ 
but $f$ never vanishes!

Answer (score 1):

1. This statement is true if $Y=\mathbb{R}$ and $M$ is path connected (no need for Banach spaces) : let $\gamma$ be a path joining $x_1$ and $x_2$. Then apply apply the classical theorem to $t \mapsto F(\gamma(t))$
2. As others pointed out, this is hopeless as soon as $Y \neq \mathbb{R}$. The reason is that behind this theorem lies the notion of connexity, and the fact the connected subset of $\mathbb{R}$ are the intervals.

Note : your question is purely topological, and the structure of vector spaces is not actually relevant here.